# How to reduce Material-UI TableFooter height

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I reduce the height of the TableFooter component? I am trying to reduce the height of the TableFooter component in materials-UI but below 56px, the height of the footer does not get any smaller. There's no problem in increasing/making it bigger, however.

I've tried using the MUI Theme override based on other articles I've read here but they also do not work.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides:{
      MuiTableRow: {
          root: { //for the body
              height: "100%"
          },
          head: { //for the head
              height: "100%"
          },
          footer: {
            height: '30px',
            minHeight: '20px',
            backgroundColor: 'grey'
          },
      }
  }
})
```

The code for my table based mostly on the Custom Pagination demo from the material-UI website aside from the codes that try to reduce the footer size.

```
<Paper className={classes.root}>
  <div className={classes.tableWrapper}>
    <Table className={classes.table} padding={"none"}>
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">Fat (g)</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
      <TableBody>
        {rows.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage).map(row => (
          <TableRow key={row.id}>
            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
              {row.name}
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        ))}
        {emptyRows > 0 && (
          <TableRow style={{ height: 48 * emptyRows }}>
            <TableCell colSpan={4} />
          </TableRow>
        )}
      </TableBody>
      <TableFooter className={classes.footer}>
        <TableRow className={classes.footer}>
          <TablePagination
            rowsPerPageOptions={[]}
            colSpan={3}
            count={rows.length}
            rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
            page={page}
            SelectProps={{
              native: true,
            }}
            onChangePage={this.handleChangePage}
            ActionsComponent={TablePaginationActionsWrapped}
            style={{ padding: 0, margin: 0 }}
          />
        </TableRow>
      </TableFooter>
    </Table>
  </div>
</Paper>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/moj46v62oy?fontsize=14

The current output where the size doesn't get any smaller than that. I was hoping to lessen the space between the top and bottom of the arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
footer: {
    "& > td > div": {
      height: 30,
      minHeight: 30
    },
    backgroundColor: "grey",
    height: 30
  }
```

This should become easier once v4 is out and global styles are being used.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/pmokwxxmvj